# OpenSUSE service: where does the log go?

Tags: opensuse

I am trying to set up an application as a service on OpenSUSE LEAP 15.
Googling around I found that one does that (or should I say "one can do that"?) by providing a file `<servicename>.service` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` and then one enables that service using YaST.
I provided such a file (copying from a `tomcat.service` file already on the machine and replacing the misc. entries with values relevant for my application).

The setup using YaST seemed to have worked OK, the service was listed and I enabled it. But now I have an issue: when I start the application using `service <servicename> start` the startup fails. Using `service <servicename>  status` I see the last 10 lines of some log which read:

```
Jun 08 14:41:04 test-vm ctlscript.sh[31955]:         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Jun 08 14:41:04 test-vm ctlscript.sh[31955]:         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
Jun 08 14:41:04 test-vm ctlscript.sh[31955]:         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:458)
...
```

This is the tail of some Java stacktrace, so obviously there is some exception while starting up.
But to be able to figure out what is going wrong I would need to see more from that log but where is this service command logging to? I.e. from which logfile does the above content of the `service ... status` command come from?

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I finally found the solution: one can use `journalctl -u <servicename>` to see all log entries of a specific service. While that doesn't answer the original question it serves the underlying purpose of the question, namely to see all log entries for a specific service.